# Gherkin scenarios, reusable steps approach or specific approach

Tags: cucumber, specflow, gherkin

I need advice on how to write scenarios. First I have to explain that we have a CQRS architecture where commands and queries are separated APIs. We specify the commands with Gherkin scenarios that are used in Specflow to create tests.

In the scenarios below the domain is that of Expenses. An expense bundle is a collection of expenses. With this scenario I want to specify and test that I can't create an expense for an expense bundle that someone else created. I can only create expenses for an expenses bundle that I created.

The following approach is that I try to reuse as many steps as possible:

```
Background: 
  Given I am declarant 'Marieke'

     Scenario: Not allowed to create expense for a bundle that was created by another declarant
     Given the following expense bundles exist
        | declarant | name             | administration    | status        |
        | Lucy      | Trip to New York | Company B.V.      | not submitted |
       When I create an expense for the following expense bundle
        | declarant | name             | administration    | status        |
        | Lucy      | Trip to New York | Company B.V.      | not submitted |
       Then the expense is not created for the expense bundle
```

The name, administration and status is maybe not relevant in above example. But in other scenario's I can reuse the 'given the following expense bundles exist' step. This saves time for the developer.

In the following approach I try to write a scenario that is better readable and more specific:

```
Background: 
  Given I am declarant 'Marieke'

    Scenario: Not allowed to create expense for a bundle that was created by another declarant
       When I create an expense for an expense bundle that was created by another declarant
       Then the expense is not created for the expense bundle
```

In this case the developer has to write a When step that will probably never be used again. Is this a problem?

I'm struggling with both options a lot in my scenarios. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to write scenarios is too explain the WHAT and WHY and have nothing about HOW things are done. The WHAT is about claiming expense bundles and in particular that you can't claim expenses for someone else. You haven't really explained WHY that is important, you could do that in the features preamble. The scenario shouldn't give a damn about HOW expense bundles are. Other problems with the scenarios are that the language seems a bit clumsy. Again you could use the preamble to explain what an expense bundle is. So I would write something like

```
Feature: Claiming an expense on an expense bundle

Explain what an expense bundle is, including the concept of ownership
Explain what an expense is
Explain why Fred should not be able to claim an expense on Susan's expense bundle

Background:
  Given users Fred and Susan
  And Susan has an expense bundle

  Scenario: Susan claims an expense
    When Susan claims an expense on her bundle
    Then the expense should be approved

  Scenario: Fred claims an expense on Susan's bundle
   When Fred claims an expense on Susan's expense bunlde
   Then the expense should be rejected
```

This would be my starting point, and I would be using this to prompt questions like

1. Why can Fred see Susan's expense bundle
2. Should we notify someone (Susan, Freds boss, Fred) when Fred tries to claim the expense
3. ...

When cuking step definition reuse is irrelevant IF you write your step definitions correctly. The correct way to write a step definitions is to make each one a single call to a helper method. In this way step definitions are reduced to performing one single function - to translate business language into a call. So it doesn't matter if a step is only used once (most aren't) because writing it is trivial.

Re-using code in helper methods is an entirely different problem, but now that we are fully in code (rather than being half way there in a step def) we can use all our normal code tools and skills to solve that problem.

Comment: Thanks. I understand your approach. What about scenarios where you create something, for example an expense bundle. Then I need to clarify what data an expense bundle contains: such as a description. Then I would start with: When Marieke creates an expense bundle with the description "Trip to New York" Then the expense bundle with the description "Trip to New York" is created And Marieke can add expenses to this bundle.

Comment: I use a combination of defaults, test structures (these mirror and sometimes extend application structures). For you particular case I would have a helper method  which I would call in the relevant step definition, perhaps something like `@bundle = create_bundle(user: @marieke, desc: "Trip to ...")`. see `https://github.com/diabolo/cuke_up/tree/master/features` for tiny sample app showing more of this approach (in ruby).

Answer (score 0):

Using Scenario Outlines could be the solution with the most reusable code(steps). I think I'm missing some context on the exact functionality but this might give you an idea how to approach this. The downside of this is that when there are a lot of parameters in the scenarios, it might not be so easy to read and interpret the test results, so it also depends on your goal and who (tester,business,developer) will be creating and interpreting the test results. More info on scenario outlines
https://www.toolsqa.com/cucumber/data-driven-testing-using-examples-keyword/

```
Abstract Scenario: Don't allow expense creation on bundle of other declarant
Given the expense bundle exists <declarant creator> 
When I create an expense for the bundle <expense creator>, <bundle administration>
Then I expect the bundle expense to be <expected>
Examples:
| bundle creator    | expense creator       | bundle administration | status        | expected    |
| Lucy              | Marieke               | Company B.V.          | Not submitted | Not allowed |
| Marieke           | Lucy                  | Company 2 V.          | Not submitted | Not allowed |
etc..
```

And happy flows

```
Abstract Scenario: Allow expense creation for blabla
Given the expense bundle exists <declarant creator>, <bundle administration> 
When I create an expense for the bundle <expense creator>, <bundle administration>
Then I expect the bundle expense to be <expected>
Examples:
| bundle creator    | expense creator       | bundle administration | status        | expected    |
| Lucy              | Lucy                  | Company B.V.          | Not submitted | Allowed     |
| Lucy              | Lucy                  | Company B.V.          | Not submitted | Allowed     |
etc..
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use the first option. It is more clear what is meant, because you can define who the other declarant is. if the developer chooses to use Marieke as the go-to declarant, the testcase fails for unclear reasons. Also, you can expand your testset with other testcases like 'Same name, same administration' if required.
Reusability is a great advantage of automating, it also saves time on communicating between yourself and the developer, which in my experience is almost as timeconsuming as writing the code myself.